# RecyclerView starting in the middle of ScrollView

Tags: android

I have scrollview. Inside that `ScrollView` I have some content on top and `RecyclerView` that starts in the middle of the screen. I want to be able to scroll down until that `RecyclerView` fill whole `ScrollView` then i want to be able to scroll in that `RecyclerView`.

Examples from existing apps: In google plus app on someone's profile, there is some info about user on top but you could scroll down to list of his posts. In Instagram or Facebook is this too.

I tried this:

First i set height of `RecyclerView` to have the same height as `ScrollView`.

Then i added `OnTouchListener` to `RecyclerView` so it will get scrolls events when `ScrollView` is scrolled down.

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(scrollView.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() <= scrollView.getScrollY() + scrollView.getHeight()){
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

It is ok when i want to scroll down but I am unable to scroll back to top to content that isn't inside `RecyclerView`.

Any ideas how to achieve that? I am also loading more content to `RecyclerView` as user scrolls down, so i don't know final height of that `RecyclerView`.

Comment: You should not have nested scrollable components

Comment: Could i achieve that without nesting them?